# Programmatic pop-up on a loaded Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, modal-dialog, popup

I am creating a sign-in/sign-out form for my school Media Center, but rather than using a Google Form, I've created a web app form deployed through Google Apps Script. (Primarily because some additional "fields" need to be sent to spreadsheet that wouldn't be appropriate in the form.)

The sign in form asks students to enter an ID number; the script then looks to see if the ID number is valid (has a corresponding student). If it does NOT, then it 1) enters NO NAME FOUND in the spreadsheet; 2) triggers an email alerting media specialist of that fact; and 3) pops up a modal dialog box on the sign-in spreadsheet (being monitored by the Media Specialist at her computer) with a notification of such, along with an audio alert.

Or, at least, that's what I'd LIKE 3) to do. I was hoping that if the spreadsheet is open (active?) on the user's computer, the script would pop up the dialog box, but it throws a Failure when executed.

The code to create the dialog box is:

```
    if (modalFlag) {
      var htmlTxt = "<h1>BAD SIGN IN</h1>";
      htmlTxt += "A student signed in with <h2>" + formObject.student_number;
      htmlTxt += "</h2> which has no corresponding name.";
      htmlTxt += "<audio id='chime' autoplay hidden='hidden'>";
      htmlTxt += "<source src='" + chimeURL + "' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>";
      var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(htmlTxt)
        .setWidth(250)
        .setHeight(300);
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
      ss.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput,'Bad Sign-in');
    }
```

My suspicion is that Google Apps Script won't run a function that'll open a dialog box on a spreadsheet that isn't actually calling the function. Can anyone confirm that - or think of a way I can get it to do so?

Comment: If you run a function with google.script.run from a web app the spreadsheet does not open like it does with a user.  There is no user interface available if there is no user.

Comment: Can you clarify what this means? "(Primarily because some additional "fields" need to be sent to spreadsheet that wouldn't be appropriate in the form.)" It is likely there is another way to handle this.

Comment: When a script opens a spreadsheet it is only opened on the server with no user interface.

Comment: What you're saying makes total sense, Cooper. I was hoping that - when the script (earlier on, not copied above) appends a row with the latest data - since the newest data appears in real-time because the spreadsheet is open on someone's computer, that the modal box might also pop up. But data is not ui.

Comment: I wonder if I were to create a sidebar that's always present on the spreadsheet, could the script update the content of the sidebar and that show on the sheet?